# XML validation error, Element not found (even though element exists and schema and xml are loaded properly, I think)

Tags: java, xml, xsd

I'm trying to validate a simple XML file against an XML schema using the following chunk of code. I'm getting an exception

```
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: cvc-elt.1: 
    Cannot find the declaration of element 'Applications'
```

and was wondering if anyone had any idea why that could be. (When I try looking at what the contents of the schema are after it is loaded, I see a bunch of grammar objects or something of that sort, with nothing indicating that the schema is loaded properly. Could that be it? If I try loading a schema with an non-existing file name, it gives me a file not found exception...so I'm getting it is finding the right schema when the right file name is given)

```
public void getPriceSummaryInfo(){
        Document doc = null;
        try {
            File fXmlFile = new File("testXML.xml");
            DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
            doc = dBuilder.parse(fXmlFile);
        } 
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
        Schema schema = getSchema("testSchema.xsd");
        Validator validator = schema.newValidator();
        validator.validate(new DOMSource(doc));
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private Schema getSchema (String xsdPath) throws Exception {
        assert xsdPath != null : "XML schema path is null.";
        SchemaFactory fact = 
                SchemaFactory.newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI);

        Schema schema;
        try {
            schema = fact.newSchema(new StreamSource(new File(xsdPath)));
        }
        catch (SAXException e) {
            throw new Exception(
                    "Unable to find target schema to validate XML.", e);
        }
        return schema;
    }
```

The xml and xsd files are:

```
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
            targetNamespace="http://www.randomthing.com"
            xmlns="http://www.randomthing.com"
            elementFormDefault="qualified">

    <xsd:element name="Applications">
        <xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:element ref="Application" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
            </xsd:sequence>
        </xsd:complexType>
    </xsd:element>

    <xsd:element name="Application">
        <xsd:annotation>
            <xsd:documentation>
             blah
            </xsd:documentation>
        </xsd:annotation>
       <xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:attribute name="id" type="xsd:long" use="required"/>
            <xsd:attribute name="name" type="xsd:string" use="required"/>
            <xsd:attribute name="order" type="xsd:long" use="required"/>
        </xsd:complexType>    
    </xsd:element>
</xsd:schema>  



<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Applications xmlns ="http://www.randomthing.com"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.randomthing.com testSchema.xsd">

    <Application id="3" name="Blah" order="2">
    </Application>
</Applications>
```

Would appreciate any pointers! Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should parse the document with namespaces, you are losing them at load time.

```
dbFactory.setNamespaceAware(true);
```

Comment: Oh, that worked! Thanks so much!
Out of curiosity, are namespaces just arbitrary 'buckets' or do they actually have anything to do with the domain specified there? Sorry, I'm new to playing around with XML and stuff.